# As ResultSetExtractor to implement SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to create a ResultSetExtractor class but, I'm not succeeding in it. The class is not compiling and I don't know why.

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContatoDao {
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    public List<Contato> setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;

        List<Contato> getAllContatoes;
        {
            return template.query("select * from CONTATO", new ResultSetExtractor<List<Contato>>() {

                @Override
                public List<Contato> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                        DataAccessException {
                    List<Contato> list = new ArrayList<Contato>();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Contato e = new Contato();
                        e.setId(rs.getLong(1));
                        e.setNome(rs.getString(2));
                        e.setEmail(rs.getString(2));
                        e.setTelefone(rs.getNString(2));
                    }
                    return list;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make the right syntax for the ResultSetExtractor

Comment: What is the error message?  The compiler will help you fix this faster than SO will.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I think it should be coded.  No compiler errors, according to IntelliJ:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContatoDao {

    private static final String SELECT_ALL = "select * from CONTATO";

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public ContatoDao(DataSource ds) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    public List<Contato> findAll() {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_ALL, rs -> {
            List<Contato> result = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Contato e = new Contato();
                e.setId(rs.getLong(1));
                e.setNome(rs.getString(2));
                e.setEmail(rs.getString(3));
                e.setTelefone(rs.getNString(4));
                result.add(e);
            }
            return result;
        });
    }
}
```

I would change that SELECT statement so it spells out the column names instead of the star notation.  I'd use the column names in the result extraction instead of column numbers.

Comment: How would I do your suggestion of making a SELECT and I wanted a single query to return an entire table, and I wanted to know how to do this with an endpoint @GetMapping

Comment: This method does return the entire table, every row.  Exposing it as a REST service is a separate matter.  It's easy to do - give this DAO to your Controller and add the mapping.  I think that's another question.  I'd accept and upvote this correct answer and submit another question.